# Convert absolute filesystem path to a file URI in a platform-agnostic way

Tags: c++, boost, uri, boost-filesystem

In C++, I'm using `boost::filesystem::path` to represent a path to an asset. I have logic to build a file URI from this absolute path. I run this code on both Windows and Linux, which has made this a non-trivial task because on the Windows file URI, there's an extra slash character I need to insert explicitly whereas the root path slash in the Linux case doubles as the host/path separator:

Windows:

```
file://localhost/C:/my/data/foo.txt
```

Linux:

```
file://localhost/my/data/foo.txt
```

And the code:

```
#ifdef WINDOWS
#define BASE_DIRECTORY "C:\\my\\data"
#elseif // assume LINUX
#define BASE_DIRECTORY "/my/data"
#endif

auto test_file = boost::filesystem::canonical(BASE_DIRECTORY) / "foo.txt";
std::string file_uri = "file://localhost/" + test_file.generic_string();
```

This doesn't quite work on the linux side, because I end up with:

```
file://localhost//my/data/foo.txt
```

Is it valid to have a double-slash after the host? If so, then this will work great as a solution I think. But I've assumed double slash after host is not valid. Is there a simple, portable solution here?

Comment: You could either start with `"file://localhost/"` and strip off a leading `'/'` from the `test_file.generic_string()` string if one is present, or you can start with `"file://localhost"` and prepend a leading `'/'` to the `test_file.generic_string()` string if not present. Both are pretty trivial to do with `std::string`